# How to get battery status of BT devices with Monterey?

Tags: macos, battery, bluetooth, monterey

Since i've upgraded to Monterey OS, running `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType` doesn't return the battery status for the BT devices connected.

Any idea how to get this information?